# Match partial text with full text and replace

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a dataset of tweets, where some tweets are original, and others are retweets. The retweets are for some reason truncated with `...`, so the whole text is not present. In my dataset the original tweet is (hopefully) always present, so I want to find the original and replace the truncated ones with it.

For example:

```
my_data <- tribble(
  ~user, ~text,
  "Peter", "Hello, this is Peter, I like ice cream!",
  "John", "RT @Peter: Hello, this is Peter, I like ...",
  "Martha", "RT @Peter: Hello, this is Peter, I like ...",
  "Julia", "Hi, I really like apples!",
  "Bjorn", "RT @Julia: I really like ..."
)
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  user   text                                       
  <chr>  <chr>                                      
1 Peter  Hello, this is Peter, I like ice cream!    
2 John   RT @Peter: Hello, this is Peter, I like ...
3 Martha RT @Peter: Hello, this is Peter, I like ...
4 Julia  Hi, I really like apples!                  
5 Bjorn  RT @Julia: I really like ...
```

I want to find every instance of `RT@ username: some text...`, and replace it with the full tweet. Basically:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  user   text                                              
  <chr>  <chr>                                             
1 Peter  Hello, this is Peter, I like ice cream!           
2 John   RT @Peter: Hello, this is Peter, I like ice cream!
3 Martha RT @Peter: Hello, this is Peter, I like ice cream!
4 Julia  Hi, I really like apples!                         
5 Bjorn  RT @Julia: Hi, I really like apples!
```

I already have extracted the handle that is being retweeted and broken it down by groups with:

```
retweet_pattern <- "^RT @([a-zA-Z0-9_]*): (.*)"
str_match(my_data$text, retweet_pattern)
```

However, I am not entirely sure how to proceed. Since the user/text pairs are not necessarily unique (i.e., one user may have multiple tweets that are retweeted), simply finding a retweet handle and changing the whole text wouldn't work. Maybe I need to use string metrics, like Levenshtein?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the retweet text completely coincides with the non-retweet data you can try this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Create a separate dataframe for retweet data
#separate the username and tweet in different columns
rt_data <- my_data %>% 
  filter(grepl('RT', text)) %>%
  separate(text, c('name', 'text'), sep = ':\\s*')

#Create a separate dataframe for tweets which are not retweets. 
no_rt_data <- my_data %>% filter(!grepl('RT', text))
  

#Clean the retweet string and find the corresponding match
#in non-retweet data
rt_data$text <- sapply(gsub('RT @\\w+:\\s*|\\s*\\.+$', '', rt_data$text), 
                       function(x) no_rt_data$text[grepl(x, no_rt_data$text)])

#Combine the username and tweet  
rt_data <- rt_data %>% unite(text, name, text, sep = ' :')

#combine the two dataframes
bind_rows(no_rt_data, rt_data)

#   user   text                                              
#  <chr>  <chr>                                             
#1 Peter  Hello, this is Peter, I like ice cream!           
#2 Julia  Hi, I really like apples!                         
#3 John   RT @Peter :Hello, this is Peter, I like ice cream!
#4 Martha RT @Peter :Hello, this is Peter, I like ice cream!
#5 Bjorn  RT @Julia :Hi, I really like apples!
```